# Unable to boot MacBook Pro 15" mid-2014 (Big Sur) after update

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, big-sur, performance

I have a **MacBook Pro 15" mid-2014** with **Big Sur** on it.
I tried to update the operating system to the latest version (**11.6.5**) using **System Update**.
During the update process it restarted itself but then wouldn't boot successfully. The boot process stops at the screen where the Apple logo and the white progress bar is visible.

I then tried to **fully turn it off by holding the power button for ten seconds** and started it again but this results in the **same problem**. I also booted it into **recovery mode** to start **Disk Utility** and used **First Aid/Verify Disk** on all volumes but it said they have no problem. Next I cleared the SMC, PRAM and NVRAM by following an article online - to no avail.

Next I **booted into recovery mode again** and **selected "Reinstall macOS"**.
At first glance the reinstallation seemed to work but after restarting, it got stuck at the same part again (Apple logo with white progress bar).

After that I created a **bootable USB device** from a **macOS virtual machine**, also with **Big Sur** on it.
I **plugged it into the MacBook and booted from it** but I **don't even reach the installation menu**. The **USB device gets recognized correctly** and it also shows that Big Sur is on it and I can select it. But during the boot it gets stuck again at the same part (Apple logo with white progress bar).

I'm quite clueless what options I have now and am very thankful for any help!

**Edit**
Here are the pictures from the verbose boot process: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpQ8S.jpg

Comment: Please reboot into Verbose Mode (hold CMD + V during boot) and use a high-speed/slow-motion video capture device (like a recent iPhone in slo-mo mode) to record the boot console text. Then please extract individual frames from this slow motion video, save them as images, and add them to your question so that we can see the boot process and the point of hanging.

Comment: @pion I've attached the pictures as requested. I hope the quality is good enough, it took me some attempts. Thanks for your help!